# Change my Trello account login from username + password to login with Google

Tags: trello

How can I change a Trello account login from using a username + password to logging in with my Google account so that I can take advantage of being able to use 2-step authentication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty simple.

Go to Trello.com, select 'Log in with Google'.

If you've never logged in with this Google account on Trello, it will ask you what to do with it. Select 'Add it to an existing account', log in to your Trello account normally, and that's it!

Comment: What can be done if you have logged into Trello before with this google account ? But want to swap the assoicated Trello account so it now works with the one that im currently logging into with a username + password.